# How to put an array in is_category

Tags: categories

I try to put an array in a is_category():

I have my array like this

```
$term_id = 7;
$taxonomy_name = 'category';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name);
$mycategory= array();
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name);
$mycategory[] = $term->term_id; 
}


$mycategory =     Array ( [0] => 23 [1] => 33 [2] => 37 [3] => 54 [4] => 56 [5] => 58 [6] => 60 [7] => 62 [8] => 64 [9] => 66 [10] => 68 [11] => 70 [12] => 72 [13] => 74 [14] => 76 )
```

Now when i put my code

```
if(is_category(array($mycategory))):
//echo 'it\'s work';
else:
//echo 'nope';
endif;
```

It's don't work

Thanks for help

Comment: If `$mycategory` is array, you don't need to put it in another array.

Comment: what you've done is `array( array( 1,2,3 ) )` when what you needed was `array( 1,2,3 )`

Comment: Thanks for info but it's not work

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: `$termchildren` is already an array of term ids if the `$term_id` is correct (if not, it might be a wp error object, check for that too).. `if(is_category($termchildren)):` will be suffice.

Comment: @Abhik it's work with $termchildren.   Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped.. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$mycategory = array(23, 33, 37);

if( is_category( $mycategory ) ) {
   echo 'yes';
} else {
   echo 'no';
}
```

[is_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) returns true if there are *any* matches.

You could try this:

```
... 
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name);
if ( is_category( $term->term_id ) ) {
   $mycategory[] = $term->term_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have yes for all the tests even if the category is not in the array "mycategory".

Comment: hello @shanebp thanks I make a edit from my question.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Hello @shanebp.  thanks for help.  But do not work. When I put manually the code it's work when I i clik on category this is not in array, I got no.  if(is_category(array(23,33,37,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76))){ echo 'yes'; } else{ echo 'no'; }   I get what I want.  Buy when I put if(is_category($mycategory) I got yes for all.

Comment: it's work I see my mistake.  I left variable  $cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(); in place off my $term_id.   Thanks it's work for if( is_category( $mycategory ) ) :   thanks again.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark.